# Error when git stash builtin calls update-index

Tags: git

I have built git 2.29.0 from source under Ubuntu bionic (completely fresh copy, using `make -d prefix=/usr USE_LIBPCRE2=YesPlease all doc`) and everything works except for when I run `git stash` which gives me the
`unknown option 'ignore-skip-worktree-entries'` error and I have to resort to the old shell-based  version `git legacy-stash`.

This error comes from the builtin stash calling the `update-index` command with this flag, so I guess that is the culprit somehow.

I have ensured I only have one git instance installed (`which -a git`) and `/usr/local/bin` where it's installed is top of the PATH etc.

Apologies that is a bit open ended, but I'd greatly appreciate any advice on next steps to troubleshoot this.

Comment: Can you show same example output? I can see that `[--[no-]ignore-skip-worktree-entries]` is a part of v2.29.2.

Comment: This suggests that you have both the old and new `git-core` programs (`/usr/libexec/git-core` or some other path) and the new `git stash` binary is running the old `git-core/git-update-index` command. The build you showed (`make -d prefix=/usr`) suggests you built binaries that will use /usr/bin and /usr/libexec/git-core, but if you're running `/usr/local/bin/git`, you probably installed the git-core directory in `/usr/local/libexec`.

Comment: Thanks @torek [are you the torek of strsep() fame for instance? if so I've had great use of your wisdom in other places]. I deleted the version in `/usr/local/libexec` and it seems to behave as expected. Thanks again! If you provide this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Same Torek, yes. :-) I'm going off line for at least a few hours now though...

Comment: for people having this problem because of git not running on its initial install path, it's possible to set the environment variable `GIT_EXEC_PATH` to the desired `libexec/git-core` path (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git has several parts, each of which install into a different location:

- user binaries go in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, typically;
- "core" binaries that implement parts of Git for front end commands to run go in `/usr/libexec/git-core` or `/usr/local/libexec/git-core`, typically, although many systems move these around; and
- documentation goes in `/usr/man` or `/usr/local/man`, typically.

When you *build* Git, the `prefix=` tells it where it will be installed in the future, so that determines where front end commands may look for the "core" parts.  When you *install* Git, you choose where to actually place the various parts.

You *can* install multiple versions of Git and have them use their own binaries (rather than other binaries) but this can be a bit tricky.  Once they are installed normally, the various parts should look for the other parts in the places where you told Git to look while you were building it.  You can tell where any particular front end is expecting its binaries by running `git --exec-path` (with no other arguments).  Note that all Git does to allow a front end to find a git-core piece is to *add* the `--exec-path` to `$PATH` if it's not already there.

I brought up an Ubuntu 18<sup>1</sup> VM and the standard Git installation there lives in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/libexec/git-core`, rather than `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/libexec`.  If you want to override the system Git installation you should overwrite these.  If you want to leave the system installation in place and have two different Git versions installed, this *can* work, but make sure that your `/usr/local/bin` front-ends are running `/usr/local/libexec/git-core/*` binaries, not `/usr/libexec/git-core/*` binaries.

---

<sup>1</sup>Not the same version, but probably uses the same paths.